# Set hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings in application.yaml

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to set the hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings property in order to use SequenceStyleGenerator, as I'm getting deprecation warnings for SequenceHiLoGenerator after upgrading to Spring Boot 1.4.0.RELEASE.

I tried adding the following entry to application.yaml but it has no effect:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      id:
        new_generator_mappings: true
```

I also tried converting to application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=true
```

Stepping through the `JpaProperties` class I can see where it's trying to parse the hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings property, but it is missing.

Is this a bug in Spring Boot, or do I have something configured incorrectly?

Comment: Spring Boot has migrated to Hibernate 5 and take a look into migrate gide - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc . All Spring Boot 1.4 changes - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes

Comment: Thanks for the link, after reading the upgrade notes more carefully I found the proper setting

Comment: NTyler - please post the "proper setting"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The correct setting, per the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes) is:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings`

Comment: Currently using Spring Boot 2 and hibernate-core 5.2.16, this setting works for me

Comment: turns out it was a different problem :)

Comment: I use the above setting even in Spring Boot 1.5